# publish int value?

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is probably a noob question. i wonder if there is any message type so that i can pass an int number to for publishing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214042/publish-int-value-?/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the various `Int` types in the [std_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs) package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-07-18**:
i have problem pass an int to std_message int16

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-07-18**:
never mind, i got it

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-18**:
Question answered? Please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-07-20**:
theres 1 more issue , the int8_t is converted to ascii in subscriber. how can i solve it please? i want to change it to int

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-20**:
? Could you update your original question with a code snippet that shows what you are trying to do?